Azure devops python API - how to add an existing work item to new pull request?
I saw the response on the other question asking the same thing (link: How to link a work item to a pull request using REST API in Azure DevOps?), but while the patch command links my PR into my work item, I want to be able to attach an existing work item while sending the POST request to create a PR. How can I achieve this?

"I saw the response on the other question" which question? Please, provide a link to the question you're referring to.


I want to be able to attach an existing work item while sending the POST request to create a PR.

You can define the workItemRefs in the Request Body to link the PR to a work item when sending the POST request Pull Requests - Create to create a PR.
Here is the sample PowerShell script
# Replace with your actual values
$organization = ""
$project = ""
$repository = ""
$sourceRefName = "refs/heads/feature-branch"
$targetRefName = "refs/heads/main"
$title = "My Pull Request"
$description = "This is a pull request"
$workItemId = "634"
$personalAccessToken = ""

# Create the JSON payload
$body = @{
    sourceRefName = $sourceRefName
    targetRefName = $targetRefName
    title = $title
    description = $description
    workItemRefs = @(@{ id = $workItemId })
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Define the URL
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repository/pullRequests?api-version=7.1"

# Send the POST request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$personalAccessToken"))
}

# Output the response
$response 


Here is the sample Python script:
import requests
import json
import base64

# Replace with your actual values
organization = ""
project = ""
repository = ""
source_ref_name = "refs/heads/feature-branch"
target_ref_name = "refs/heads/main"
title = "My Pull Request"
description = "This is a pull request"
work_item_id = "634"
personal_access_token = ""

# Create the JSON payload
body = {
    "sourceRefName": source_ref_name,
    "targetRefName": target_ref_name,
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
    "workItemRefs": [{"id": work_item_id}]
}

# Define the URL
url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/pullRequests?api-version=7.1"

# headers 
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + base64.b64encode(f":{personal_access_token}".encode("ascii")).decode("ascii"),
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Send the POST request
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(body))

# Format and output the response
formatted_response = json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)
print(formatted_response)


Test result:

